# setting recurrent payments for PayPal

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I have two questions about recurrent payments for PayPal. 
Question1: I have a manager account, I test the connection with curl to the https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com. Eventhough all info are correct USER VENDOR PARTNER and PWD I have always the 1 response with failed authentication

Question2: How can I add users programtically to the paypal manager as I try to intgrate recurrent paiment to an online site using C# and PayFlowPro API

Thanks

Comment: can you check whether you are able to login to the manager interface here: https://manager.paypal.com/ ?